# Formatando valor com NumeralJs

Tags: javascript, numeraljs

Estou precisando formatar um valor para o formato monetário brasileiro, `R$ 0.000,00`. Mas no banco de dado os valores estão em decimal, no formato `0.00`.

Mas quando o valor `20.00` é usado, recebo `2000` e não `20`. Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo de errado? Já vi a documentação mas não encontrei nada sobre valores com 2 casas.

```
var valuePrince = numeral(20.00);
var valueFormat = valuePrince.format('$ 0,0.[00]');
```

Estou usando a versão 2.0.6 do [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JavaScript, como só existe um tipo numérico (excluindo o `bigint`), não há uma distinção propriamente dita entre um `int` e um `float`. Portanto, `20.00` é a mesma coisa que `20`.

Então, na sua chamada à `numeral`, você está, no fundo, fazendo o seguinte:

```js
numeral(20);
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
function test(num) {
  console.log(num);
}

test(20.33); // 20.33
test(20.00); // 20
```

Além disso, `Numeral.js` não suporta o formato monetário brasileiro nativamente. Você deve registrá-lo para que possa usá-lo. Assim:

```js
// Todas as opções podem ser encontradas em:
// http://numeraljs.com/#locales
numeral.register('locale', 'pt-BR', {
  delimiters: {
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ','
  },
  currency: {
    symbol: 'R$'
  }
});

numeral.locale('pt-BR');

const price = numeral(20.00);
const formatted = price.format('$ 0,0.00');

console.log(formatted); // R$ 20,00
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

---

A título de curiosidade, se o seu ambiente suportar, você pode utilizar a API [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat), que te dá uma interface bem mais robusta, de forma nativa, e que ainda suporta diversos idiomas.

Então, para formatar um número para o formato monetário brasileiro usando essa API, você pode fazer assim:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL'
})

console.log(formatter.format(20)); // R$ 20,00
console.log(formatter.format(1234567.89)); // R$ 1.234.567,89
```

Comment: Formidável sua resposta, como a resposta vinha do back-end, e como não é fortemente tipado, provavelmente ele deveria reconhecer que era um string, usei o `NUMBER(prince)`, e fiz como vc falou deu certinho. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente, você só precisa utilizar a [API de internacionalização](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) do JavaScript, ela é nativa:

```
const formatMoneyBR = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format
const valueFormat = formatMoneyBR(1234567.89)
console.log(valueFormat) // R$ 1.234.567,89
```

Bem simples!